# Can I read posts from a group where user is not admin?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using Facebook Graph API and I need to fetch the feed of a group where the logged user is not an admin. Is it possible?

In the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.10/group) only talks about public groups and groups where user is admin (`user_managed_groups` permission). But, what about those groups where is member but not admin?

Comment: Unless the group is public, no way.

Comment: Seriously? Is there any reason for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After posting in a Facebook Developers group, I found out that, actually, API does not allow that operation, so far.

Comment: if the group is public can we get the feed through facebook graph api without having the app added to the group? Please let me know if you know anything about this, I have been googling for hours but i am only able to get the feed for the group im an admin of